# Ruby object initialization

Tags: ruby, class, initialization

So i wrote this code and it works when i put student outside the class and pass the parameter students to search. But when i try to run it like this it says that students is undefined. I feel like I'm supposed to use the initialize method but i am not able to figure out how to use it in this situation

```
class Student

def search(name)
i = 0;

  students = [

   {:firstname => "John", :lastname => "LastnameJohn",  :phonenumber => 123456789},

   {:firstname => "Ken", :lastname => "Lastnameken",  :phonenumber => 456734244},

   {:firstname => "Marisa", :lastname => "lastnamemarisa",  :phonenumber => 443234567},
   {:firstname => "Ken", :lastname => "Kenlastname",  :phonenumber => 456734244}
  ]

  while i < students.length
    if(students[i][:firstname] == name)
      puts students[i]
    end
    i = i + 1;
  end
 end
end

a = Student.new
a.search("John")
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define lists like that inside a method. Either you should pass them in, or you should have them defined in another class or module.

For example:

```
students = [
    {:firstname => "John", :lastname => "LastnameJohn",  :phonenumber => 123456789},
    {:firstname => "Ken", :lastname => "Lastnameken",  :phonenumber => 456734244},
    {:firstname => "Marisa", :lastname => "lastnamemarisa",  :phonenumber => 443234567},
    {:firstname => "Ken", :lastname => "Kenlastname",  :phonenumber => 456734244}
]

class Student
  def initialize(list)
    @list = list
  end

  def search(name)
    @list.select do |student|
      student[:firstname] == name
    end.each do |student|
      puts student.inspect
    end
  end
end

a = Student.new(students)
a.search("John")
```

This uses the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) method `select` to filter out the rows you're interested in rather than your original code.

Comment: and what is do |student|? I'm sorry i just started learning ruby. Im so confused

Comment: Read through the Enumerable documentation I've linked to. It explains with many, many examples. The `do |...|` notation is how you call a block, akin to `function(...) {  }` in JavaScript.

Comment: The block technique can be very unusual at first, but it's really the backbone of most Ruby code. Spend some time experimenting with how it works and what its limitations are.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is correct. I don't get any error message when I run it. However, since `students` never changes its value, I would define it as a constant member of the class:

```
class Student

  STUDENTS = [ .... ]

  def search(name)
      .... # do something with STUDENTS
  end

end
```